# JavaScript/JQuery - can you pass a reference to a function and then execute it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Based on the JavaScript example below, is there a way to pass a reference to function `f` to the `promptForProceed` function and have it conditionally executed in `promptForProceed`?

Could you also do this if the `f`function took some parameters (ie: `f(a, b, c) { ... }`)?

```
function f() {
    //Do stuff..
}

function promptForProceed(myFunction) {  // <------ PASS FUNCTION AS PARAMETER
    $("#div-dialog-proceed").dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Stay on current page": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Continue": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                myFunction(); // <---------  CALL FUNCTION
            }
        }
    });
}
```

---

**Update**: Think I like the option of using an anonymous function parameter:

```
promptForProceed(function() { //Do stuff like call f(a,b,c) });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but you should probably not name both of them `f` or it will be confusing what is going on.  The line you called `f()` on is calling the parameter, not the function `f` (unless that's what you passed)

To pass parameters, pass `promptForProceed(myFunction, a, b, c)` and then call with `myFunction(a, b, c)`

Answer (score 2):

of course you can. Functions are objects!

Comment: Functions are not objects, functions get passed by copy, objects get passed by reference.

Comment: @Ally "Every function in JavaScript is actually a Function __object__" -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Functions are first-class objects in JavaScript and can be passed as parameters.

In fact, your syntax is correct. It should work already :)

Comment: What if f took parameters?  Could you pass `f(a,b,c)` to the `promptForProceed` function?

Comment: @Marcus Where are the parameters coming from?

Comment: @Marcus yes. Javascript is pretty intuitive if you ask me

Comment: you would pass (f, a, b, c), and then call f(a, b, c)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  What you have should work.  Passing parameters in is fine too.

You should also look in to the call method of function which allows you to set the scope

```
myFunction.call(object);
```

The apply method allows you to pass arguments in as an array.

```
myFunction.apply([param1, param2]);
```

Also, you should understand 'closures' and how scope works when passing functions around like this.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)#JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

```
promptForProceed(f, f_parameter)
```

Then pass f_parameter to f()